# Copy folder content to a named volume in Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker

I have a named volume:

```
{
    "CreatedAt": "2019-11-18T07:36:02Z",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Labels": null,
    "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/example_uploads/_data",
    "Name": "example_uploads",
    "Options": null,
    "Scope": "local"
}
```

It's mounted to my container:

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "example_uploads",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/example_uploads/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ]
```

I would like to copy the content (including sub folders) from a local folder to the volume. I have tried this:

```
docker cp folder-with-sub-folders container_name:/example_uploads
```

This doesn't return any errors but it's not working. The files are not being copied.
I have used this answer as a guide: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25245#issuecomment-365980572

I would be very thankful if anyone could point me in the right direction to get this working.

Comment: if any of the answers solved your issue please accept the appropriate answer to share the resolution with the community. If not please provide further information or share your own solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy to the destination your volume is mounted to.
In your case to `/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads` not `example_uploads`

```
docker cp folder-with-sub-folders container_name:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
```

Comment: Thank you @clemens-kaserer but I don't thinks it's working. Do you know how I can `ls` the volume to check if the content has been copied?

Comment: `docker exec CONTAINERNAME ls /var/www/html/wp-content/upload`

Comment: additionally, you could connect into the container and check the contents yourself with `docker exec -it CONTAINERNAME bash`

Comment: Last but not least you can check the content of your volume on your host (if you have the rights to go into the folder) by checking the contents of `/var/lib/docker/volumes/example_uploads/_data`

Answer (score 0):

The [issue 25245](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25245) mentioned in the OP now (Dec. 2022) includes [a possible script](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25245#issuecomment-1342425828) detailed in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/BraINstinct0/5ff8d62efdcd4bb0931e5def4e353a08) by **Apparatus_Zero**:

```bash
# CP2DockerVol.sh
# Syntax: . ./CP2DockerVol.sh Volume_Name src dst

# check if docker is running
docker 1> /dev/null
# success?
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        # folder/file exist?
        if test -f "$2"; then
                docker container create --name dummy -v $1:/root tianon/true
                docker cp "$2" dummy:"/root/$3"
                docker rm dummy
                echo "Copied $2 to $3 in Volume $1"
        else
                echo "$2 does not exist!"
        fi
else
        echo "Docker is not running!"
fi
```

---

But it refers also to [dorintt](https://github.com/dorintt)'s [solution](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25245#issuecomment-571632604) as way better for general usage. (Swapping out `hello-world` with `tianon/true` will be marginally faster in that case, too)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# docker-volume-cp

SOURCE=$1
DEST=$2

SOURCE_ARR=(${SOURCE//:/ })
DEST_ARR=(${DEST//:/ })


if [[ ${#SOURCE_ARR[@]} -eq 2 && ${#DEST_ARR[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
        VOL=${SOURCE_ARR[0]}
        VOL_PATH=${SOURCE_ARR[1]}
        HOST_PATH=${DEST_ARR[0]}

        docker container create --name docker_volume_cp -v $VOL:/volume hello-world
        CMD="docker cp docker_volume_cp:/volume/$VOL_PATH $HOST_PATH"
        #echo "$CMD"
        $CMD
        docker rm docker_volume_cp

elif [[ ${#SOURCE_ARR[@]} -eq 1 && ${#DEST_ARR[@]} -eq 2 ]]; then
        VOL=${DEST_ARR[0]}
        VOL_PATH=${DEST_ARR[1]}
        HOST_PATH=${SOURCE_ARR[0]}

        docker container create --name docker_volume_cp -v $VOL:/volume hello-world
        CMD="docker cp $HOST_PATH docker_volume_cp:/volume/$VOL_PATH"
        #echo "$CMD"
        $CMD
        docker rm docker_volume_cp
else
        echo "Usage:"
        echo " volume --> host: $0 VOLUME:VOL_PATH HOST_PATH"
        echo " host --> volume: $0 HOST_PATH VOLUME:VOL_PATH"
fi
```

> ```
> ./docker-volume-cp myvolume_dir/. myvolume_copy:.
> ```
>
> Copy all contents of host directory "`myvolume_dir`" into volume "`myvolume_copy`", which is created if it does not already exist)

---

The same issue includes a [variation of that script](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25245#issuecomment-1442225218), from [Karl Forner](https://github.com/kforner)

> I improved a bit the script from @dorintt to avoid container name collisions, for example if executed concurrently.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# borrowed from https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25245
# improved not to use global name docker_volume_cp for the temp container name

SOURCE=$1
DEST=$2

SOURCE_ARR=(${SOURCE//:/ })
DEST_ARR=(${DEST//:/ })

if [[ ${#SOURCE_ARR[@]} -eq 2 && ${#DEST_ARR[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
        VOL=${SOURCE_ARR[0]}
        VOL_PATH=${SOURCE_ARR[1]}
        HOST_PATH=${DEST_ARR[0]}

        id=$(docker container create  -v $VOL:/volume hello-world)
        CMD="docker cp $id:/volume/$VOL_PATH $HOST_PATH"
        #echo "$CMD"
        $CMD
        docker rm $id

elif [[ ${#SOURCE_ARR[@]} -eq 1 && ${#DEST_ARR[@]} -eq 2 ]]; then
        VOL=${DEST_ARR[0]}
        VOL_PATH=${DEST_ARR[1]}
        HOST_PATH=${SOURCE_ARR[0]}

        id=$(docker container create --name docker_volume_cp -v $VOL:/volume hello-world)
        CMD="docker cp $HOST_PATH $id:/volume/$VOL_PATH"
        #echo "$CMD"
        $CMD
        docker rm $id
else
        echo "Usage:"
        echo " volume --> host: $0 VOLUME:VOL_PATH HOST_PATH"
        echo " host --> volume: $0 HOST_PATH VOLUME:VOL_PATH"
fi
```